# RxJava block a thread awaiting an interaction but avoiding a race condition

Tags: rx-java, observable

I am a total beginner with RxJava so apologies if this is obvious ...

I  want to make a server call which **synchronously** gets back an `id`. I have a independent **asynchronous** event mechanism for receiving notifications back to my client app which I map to a rxjava stream. I am expecting a notification "later" with the aforementioned `id`.

Normally I will of course consume these notification asynchronously but I also want to demonstrate that I can block, waiting for the relevant Notification (filtering on the aforementioned `id`).

1. myObservables is `Observable<Notification>`
2. client app makes a call to remote server that gets a `id`.
3. Now I want to block until I get a notification related to my id. Something like 
   `Notification notn = ... myObservables(notn -> notn.getId().equals(id)).toBlocking() ....`

I presume there must be a simple pattern for this e.g. a way at step #1 to queue up notifications from that point onwards to avoid the race condition  at #3 where Notification has already arrived before we start waiting for it?

EDIT : I following approach which seems to work. Is it sensible or is there a better way ...

```
// This is NOT a idiomatic pattern, only used to demo how you would blocking for
// the Notification

// Avoid race cond by storing up the notifications
ReplaySubject<Notification> mySubject = ReplaySubject.create();
myNotnObservables.subscribe(mySubject);

final Long id = // obtain id via a synchronous request to server.

return mySubject.timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
filter(notn -> notn.getId().equals(id)).
toBlocking().first();
```

Comment: Let me check if I'm understanding correctly: you have two events, the result of the id call and the notification, and you want to do something only when both events have already occurred.

Comment: Sorry no; I have updated question to clarify that original request retrieving back the id is a traditional blocking invocation (not using rxjava).